# How can I get API data with models on OkHttpClient

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I want to pull data from api with OkHttpClient. Sample data I want to pull: https://dummyjson.com/products

I created two models. I think I created the models correctly. What do you think I did wrong? I created getter and setter methods for model fields. I didn't add it here.

```
public class TestModel {

    public class ProductList {
        private List<Product> products;
        private int total;
        private int skip;
        private int limit;
    }

    public class Product {
        private int id;
        private String title;
        private String description;
        private double price;
        private double discountPercentage;
        private double rating;
        private int stock;
        private String brand;
        private String category;
        private String thumbnail;
        private List<String> images;
    }
}
```

When I write the code below with OkHttpClient, I get a null error. I don't think data is null.

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public void GetFromServer(String _serviceUrl) throws Exception {
    String absoluteUrl = baseUrl + "/" + _serviceUrl;
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(absoluteUrl)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Logging.Error("GetFromServer is Failure. Endpoint : " + absoluteUrl + " Error Message : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String json = response.body().string();

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    TestModel.ProductList productList = gson.fromJson(json, TestModel.ProductList.class);

                    List<TestModel.Product> products = productList.getProducts();
                    for (TestModel.Product product : products) {
                        System.out.println("Product Title: " + product.getTitle());
                        System.out.println("Description: " + product.getDescription());
                       
                    }
                }
                else {
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, make sure you have the correct URL.

Comment: Make those inner classes static nested classes instead.

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace of the exception to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you added to manifest internet permission use:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Make sure you call your method with correct argument:

```
    try {
        GetFromServer("products");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

baseUrl should be:

```
String baseUrl = "https://dummyjson.com";
```

Your testModel class lacks gett-er methods, also make the inner classes static:

```
public class TestModel {
    public static class ProductList {
        private List<Product> products;
        private int total;
        private int skip;
        private int limit;

        public List<Product> getProducts() {
            return products;
        }
    }
    public static class Product {
        private int id;
        private String title;
        private String description;
        private double price;
        private double discountPercentage;
        private double rating;
        private int stock;
        private String brand;
        private String category;
        private String thumbnail;
        private List<String> images;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
    }
}
```

Carefully analyze logcat for any errors.

Comment: The most important change in your answer is probably the introduction of static on those nested classes.

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work. Logcat error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference`.

Comment: @avcismail relevant logs - not necessary exceptions - could be earlier in logcat. For me those changes work, take a look at my test project on github: https://github.com/luskan/SoTest1 in logcat I can see products printed

Comment: if it still wont work, copy paste more logcat and paste to question - make it include the NPE excpeption and few seconds of logs before it

Comment: @marcinj yes, it's worked. Thank you. My mistake, I sent the parameter as products/1. I had to send it as products and get all the data.

Answer (score 0):

you should  mark the product class to Static,like:

```
public static class Product
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an issue with the JSON structure and how you're trying to parse it with Gson.

In the JSON, the outer object has a field named "products," which contains an array of product objects. However, your TestModel.ProductList class doesn't have a corresponding field for "products." Instead, it has fields like "total," "skip," and "limit."

To fix this issue, you need to modify your model classes to match the JSON structure. Here's how you can do it:

```
public class TestModel {
    public static class ProductList {
        private List<Product> products;

        public List<Product> getProducts() {
            return products;
        }
    }

    public static class Product {
        private int id;
        private String title;
        private String description;
        private double price;
        private double discountPercentage;
        private double rating;
        private int stock;
        private String brand;
        private String category;
        private String thumbnail;
        private List<String> images;

        // Add getter and setter methods for the fields here
    }
}
```

I've removed the "total," "skip," and "limit" fields from the ProductList class because they don't exist in your JSON data. You can add getter and setter methods for the fields in the Product class as needed.

With these modifications, this Gson parsing code should work as expected:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
TestModel.ProductList productList = gson.fromJson(json, TestModel.ProductList.class);

List<TestModel.Product> products = productList.getProducts();
for (TestModel.Product product : products) {
    System.out.println("Product Title: " + product.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Description: " + product.getDescription());
    // Print other product details as needed
}
```

Please update the model class as above and make sure that the JSON response in the API matches the structure you want to parse.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Sarah, thank you for answer. I tryed but it's not worked.